# How to CALL TRANSACTION in pop-up window?

Tags: abap, alv

i have a problem with call transaction in ALV.
and now i want to call transaction when i double click on row in my popup. Its possible or not?

Thanks for answers
I use user_command '&IC1' -double click to call a popup window with data :

```
        IF selfield-fieldname = 'MATNR'.
        PERFORM popup.
```

FORM popup:

```
FORM popup.
DATA: wa_data LIKE zdata.

CLEAR: wa_data.
REFRESH it_data.

LOOP AT t_data.
CLEAR: wa_data.
MOVE-CORRESPONDING t_data TO wa_data.
APPEND wa_data TO it_data.
ENDLOOP.

CALL SCREEN 200
  STARTING AT 20 20
  ENDING   AT 200 90.

ENDFORM.
```

its implementation and definition in my top: lcl_handle_events

```
CLASS lcl_handle_events DEFINITION.
PUBLIC SECTION.
METHODS: on_double_click FOR EVENT double_click OF cl_salv_events_table
IMPORTING row column.
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_handle_events DEFINITION

CLASS lcl_handle_events IMPLEMENTATION.
METHOD on_double_click.
PERFORM get_po_ord_info USING row column.
ENDMETHOD.                    "on_double_click
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_handle_events IMPLEMENTATION
```

And this is in ALV include:

```
FORM get_po_ord_info USING row TYPE salv_de_row
  column TYPE salv_de_column.

IF column EQ 'MATNR'.
  SET PARAMETER ID 'MAT' FIELD t_dost-MATNR.
  SET PARAMETER ID 'WRK' FIELD t_dost-WERKS.
  CALL TRANSACTION 'ZCO06' AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN.
 ENDIF.
ENDIF.

ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Just use standard double click event. What's the problem?

Comment: I implented class lcl_handle_events to double click in top and form get_po_ord_info with call transaction in alv but still doesnt work.

Comment: Give the full code of your lcl_handle_events as well as snippet where you attach handlers and call grid.

Comment: i add full code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly get in what order you call your pieces, but your code works for me like this:

```
CLASS lcl_handle_events DEFINITION.
PUBLIC SECTION.
METHODS: on_double_click FOR EVENT double_click OF cl_salv_events_table IMPORTING row column.
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_handle_events DEFINITION

CLASS lcl_handle_events IMPLEMENTATION.
METHOD on_double_click.
IF column EQ 'MATNR'.
SET PARAMETER ID 'MAT' FIELD t_dost-MATNR.
SET PARAMETER ID 'WRK' FIELD t_dost-WERKS.
CALL TRANSACTION 'MB51' AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN.
ENDIF.
ENDMETHOD.                    "on_double_click
ENDCLASS.                    "lcl_handle_events IMPLEMENTATION

START-OF-SELECTION.

DATA: wa_data LIKE zdata.
CLEAR: wa_data, it_data.

LOOP AT t_data.
CLEAR: wa_data.
MOVE-CORRESPONDING t_data TO wa_data.
APPEND wa_data TO it_data.
ENDLOOP.

 DATA: o_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.
 DATA: lx_msg TYPE REF TO cx_salv_msg.
  TRY.
    cl_salv_table=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = o_alv
      CHANGING
        t_table      = it_data ).
  CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO lx_msg.
 ENDTRY.

 DATA: handle TYPE REF TO lcl_handle_events.
 CREATE OBJECT handle.
 DATA: lr_events TYPE REF TO cl_salv_events_table.
 CALL METHOD o_alv->GET_EVENT
  RECEIVING
    VALUE  = lr_events.
 SET HANDLER handle->on_double_click FOR lr_events.

 o_alv->display( ).
```

You can also call popup  window via `CALL SCREEN...STARTING` in `on_double_click` method instead of calling tcode, but you can do **either** of these actions, you cannot start new transaction in popup window. 
The only workaround here is to to call modal window inside your Z-transaction or to use [POPUP_WITH_TABLE_DISPLAY](http://abapmaster.com/abap/tag/popup_with_table_display/) FM if you only need table output in your popup.

P.S. Also your `IF column EQ 'MATNR'` is redundant as you already check `selfield-fieldname` when invoking the event.